# Привязать модель и вид к существующему div backbone

Tags: javascript, dom, события

Гайз, нужна помощь, не могу понять, каким образом я могу привязать модель и вид к уже существущему массиву элементов в DOM дереве ( в div.container у меня есть несколько div.widget ), имеется такой код:

```
// Model
V.Models.Shortcode = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// Shortcodes Collection Init
V.Collections.Shortcodes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: V.Models.Shortcode,
});
```

При загрузке iframe подгружаем коллекцию и запихиваем в нее данные моделей полученные из storage, что сформировался на сервере:

```
$('#preview').on('load', function() {

    var ShortcodesCollection = new V.Collections.Shortcodes( Vision.ShortcodeStorage );

    var Preview = new V.Views.Preview({
        collection: ShortcodesCollection,
        el: $('.container')
    });

    Preview.render();

});
```

Далее в дело вступает собственно View моего Preview с коллекцией внутри:

```
// Collection View in iframe
V.Views.Preview = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
    return this;
  },

  addOne: function(ad) {
    var shortcodeView = new V.Views.Shortcode({ model: ad });
    shortcodeView.render();
  }

});
```

в функции addOne мы пробегаемся по каждой модели и формируем View для нее:

```
// Shortcode View
V.Views.Shortcode = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .vswidget' : 'SomeActionOnView'
    },

    render: function(){
        //console.log(this.el);
        //console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    },

    SomeActionOnView: function(){
        console.log(this);
    }

});
```

Собственно вопрос, каким образом я могу привзять V.Views.Shortcode к каждому div с классом .widget чтобы повесить события? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в лоб никак. Backbone отдельно, DOM отдельно. Что бы их все таки связать, необходимо, что бы каждый HTML Item имел либо уникальный ID, либо уникальный класс.

У вас должно быть тогда так:

```html
<div class="list">
  <div id="1" class="list-item">One</div>
  <div id="2" class="list-item">Two</div>
  <div id="3" class="list-item">Three</div>
  <div id="4" class="list-item">Four</div>
</div>
```

Дальше уже в рендере или вьюхе вы находите в доме нужный DOM Item и связываете.

Но лучше всего сделать так, как я наводил в ответе на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600868/backbone-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/600923)

Comment: спасибо, уже реализовал, у каждого дива уже был id и я привязал к каждой модели id атрибут соответствующий существующему DOM элементу и через collection.each привязал модельку. Поставлю ваш ответ как решение :)